# Saving a cloned div into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, jquery-clone

I am new to web Development and am working with **C#** for Server Side and **HTML/CSS/JS/JQuery** for Client side. I have a form with multiple fields which upon being submitted saves the data into SQL database. I have used asp.net controls (textboxes, checkboxes etc) because they are easier to access on the server-side using their ids.

For example:

> string myEmail1 = txtBxEmail1.Text;   (where txtBxEmail is the id of
>   the Text Box)

I am saving the myEmail string into the intended column in my db with a query like:

> string query = "insert into My_Table(Email, Phone....) values('"" + myEmail +
>   "','" + myPhone + "','" +......"')";

Now, I have to clone huge chunk of my form to let user add information for a different entity. I was easily able to clone portion of the form using jQuery's Clone method. However the problem is, **saving these values into DB**. The above method does not seem to work now since, they do not have ids. Even if I assign incremental ids for the cloned divs, like txtBxEmail2, txtBxEmail3..... which was the simplest way to go about it, they do not exist before the program runs so I cannot assign their value into a string like above.

If anyone could help me understand how to save these cloned values into SQL. Any form of recommendation/direction/snippet would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but please investigate parameterised queries, as you're vulnerable to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I am assuming this is in ASP web forms? You can do this without using jquery, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263533/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-dynamic-textboxes-in-asp-net-web-forms